# Using CDatabase to open a ACCDB file is displaying a Select Database Source window

Tags: ms-access, visual-c++, mfc, cdatabase

I have a `CDatabase`.

One of my users has Access 2021 x64 installed. He runs the 64 bit edition of my software.

It opens a database like this:

```
CString strDBConnectString = L"Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=<path to db>;Pwd=";
m_Database.OpenEx(strDBConnectString, CDatabase::noOdbcDialog)
```

It refused to work on his PC and shows:

[image]

Why is it showing this? My development PC has Office 365 x64 and the same code works fine.

So what underlying issue is forcing this window to display?

---

> Are you sure that the required driver you ask for is installed under this name?
> Yes, I am. This is because I do not use a literal text value here but I detect it by examining the JET drivers list:

```
// We now iterate the JET drivers list and locate a valid MDB driver
CString CCommunityTalksApp::GetJETDriverEx(bool bAccDbMode)
{
    CString         strDriver;
    CString         strName, strNameLower, strValue;
    CString         strDefaultDriver = _T("Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)");
    CString         strDBType = _T("(*.mdb)");
    CStringArray    aryStrDrivers;
    TCHAR           szBuf[2001]{};
    WORD            cbBufMax = 2000;
    WORD            cbBufOut;
    TCHAR* pszBuf = szBuf;

    if (SQLGetInstalledDrivers(szBuf, cbBufMax, &cbBufOut))
    {
#ifdef _WIN64
        strDefaultDriver = _T("Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)");
        strDBType = _T("(*.mdb, *.accdb)");
#else
        if (bAccDbMode)
        {
            strDefaultDriver = _T("Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)");
            strDBType = _T("(*.mdb, *.accdb)");
        }
#endif

        while (*pszBuf)
        {
            strName = CString(pszBuf);
            strNameLower = strName;
            strNameLower.MakeLower();

            if (strNameLower.Find(strDBType) != -1)
            {
                aryStrDrivers.Add(strName);
                if (strName.CollateNoCase(strDefaultDriver) == 0)
                {
                    strDriver = strName;
                    break;
                }
            }

            pszBuf += strName.GetLength() + 1;
        }


        if (strDriver.IsEmpty() && aryStrDrivers.GetSize() > 0)
        {
            // Try and use the first MDB driver we found
            strDriver = aryStrDrivers.GetAt(0);
        }
    }

    // Make a note of the driver
    AfxGetApp()->WriteProfileString(_T("Options"), _T("JET Connection Driver"), strDriver);

    return strDriver;
}
```

Comment: What is the `L` for? I presume you have an actual path in place of `<path to db>`.

Comment: Naive question, is the ODBC driver installed on the client machine? It's name must be entered exactly as it appears in the installed driver description (install & run the ODBC Data Source Administrator application). Maybe missing some [redistributable](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920)? Also, is the [connection-string](https://www.connectionstrings.com/access/) correct? These should best be in some configuration file or in the registry (you will have to implement a "Connection Settings" dialog - user-editable).

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou I ran the ODBC x64 Drivers and it was listed there. I can manually start Access. I also tried the 365 redistributable as there does not seem to be a 2021 version

Comment: Found [this](https://help.interfaceware.com/v6/connect-to-microsoft-access-odbc). Sorry, can't help any further.

Comment: Are you sure that the required driver you ask for is installed under this name?